# Is there a tool to display WiFi information in console?

Tags: networking, wifi, networkmanager

Can I view detected WiFi networks details (like signal strength, encryption etc.) in command line? The more detailed - the better.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
```

Assuming your wireless is `wlan0`, of course. If you're not sure, `iwconfig` should tell you.

Comment: But it only shows 4 networks while the GUI WiFi applet shows 5. I am curious who is lying...

Comment: @Ivan I think the GUI applet has some kind of caching and/or sets the limit for a viable wireless network higher or lower than the defaults in iwlist

Answer (score 16):

Under Linux, you can use the `iw*` series of commands to configure and display information about wireless networks:

- iwconfig - configure a wireless network interface
- iwlist  - Get more detailed wireless information from a wireless interface
- iwpriv - configure optionals (private) parameters of a wireless network interface
- iw - show / manipulate wireless devices and their configuration

Comment: Note: `iw` is the second generation utility, and should be used in preference over `iwconfig`, `iwlist` and `iwpriv`.

Answer (score 8):

[Here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-find-out-wireless-network-speed-signal-strength.html) is a rather comprehensive list. One particularly nice way is:

```
watch -n 1 cat /proc/net/wireless
```

Comment: This is good.   Needs no dependencies (on my embedded Linux)

Answer (score 3):

Actually are all commands (`iwconfig`, `iwlist`, ...) replaced with newest tool `iw`. to show signal and other info:

```
iw wlan0 link
```

where `wlan0` is interface name.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager
nmcli dev wifi
```

Comment: (Which will only work if you have network manager installed and running).

Comment: @dirkt you right, I am going to update my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I like the colorized output of this command

Comment: The only command that listed all wifi networks and their signal strength on an interface that "doesn't support scanning" according to `iwlist wlan0 scan`.

Answer (score 1):

To fetch wireless signal informations you can use this command :

```
tail /proc/net/wireless
```

result:

[image: result]

Comment: welcome to U&L, please do not post text as image, log files can be copy/pasted for a better reading.

Comment: Ok I will. Thanks for the helpful advice!